# Dialogues without the IBM Cloud UI of the Watson Conversation service

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I would like a way to build a dialogue through classes. For example, I could create and instantiate a class called dialog and a class named node. When instantiating the Dialog class, I could have a method that would add nodes to the dialog. So I would build a whole dialog programmatically without having to use the Conversation Tool or API/Watson conversation service, in other words without use the front-end web of IBM Cloud for dialogues. Is it possible? What are all the possibilities of working with Watson Conversation Service?

Answer (score 0):

Watson Assistant (WA) has a "Workspace" API which allows you to programmatically build/edit your workspace.

You can either add some components directly, or build the whole workspace locally and then push it to WA.

The documentation starts here.

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl#workspaces-api

There are also a number of SDKs which will allow you to do this through code, reducing the need to build from scratch.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud